# which user is exactly logged in so that we can fetch particular data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I know that I can check if user is logged in or not by `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` but I have alot of data stored in my firebase realtime database. So, in the login activity I am writing `onStart()` and there itself it checks that user is logged in or not. But according to my application if the user is logged in then it moves directly into that intent where it shows user own data stored in firebase. So, for doing that and showing user's data I want to know exactly which user logged in, so that I can fetch it's details and show on the profile's page.

Comment: I don't understand.  Are you saying that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` doesn't tell you exactly which user is signed in?  That's precisely what it's intended to do.

Comment: Hi Doug, actually I had stored data in real-time DB without using user id as any child node. I am only putting the data which are needed so there is no UID node there. Then how to get the detail please help

Comment: If there is no UID in the written data, then it's not possible to identify who wrote it.  It's very important to include the UID to identify the user.

Comment: I am taking their mobile number and making the node of mobile number and storing their data at that node. So, now if the user has been logged in then it should directly open userProfile.java and fetches the information of user. Now, how to fetch that it's confusing me as I am not storing userid anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use the user id obtained from this call:

```
String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

It uniquely identifies the user and can be used as an index in a database.

Comment: Hi Rediska, actually I had stored data in real-time DB without using user id as any child node. I am only putting the data which are needed so there is no UID node there. Then how to get the detail please help

Comment: Well, then how would you know which data belong to which user?

Comment: I am taking their mobile number and making the node of mobile number and storing their data at that node. So, now if the user has been logged in then it should directly open userProfile.java and fetches the information of user. Now, how to fetch that it's confusing me as I am not storing userid anywhere

Comment: You can use user.getMobileNumber(); to fetch the user number and do your work with that